# Animation: mid-state

Tags: xna, c#, textures, animation, monogame

At the moment I have a simple static texture. Now I want to animate my sprite. The texture is a simple human. When the user press the enter button, the human gets into state2. This is the standart state during gameplay. If the user presses now "space" the sprite should get into state4(4th texture). This would be very unsmooth, so I decided to make a State3(ist just displayed very short to make the animation smooth). Now the sprite is in state4. If the user now releas the "space"-key the sprite should return into State2. For smoothness there is State3 short between.

I use XNA. I have 4 states:

**State1** *press enter*" --> **State2** ---  "*press space*" --> (short **State3** for smoothness) --> **State4** --> "*release space*" --> (short **State3**) --> **State2**

I hope you understand what I mean.

How can I solve this animation? Should I change the texture of the sprite?

Comment: You're going to have to try and describe the problem a little better. If the problem is State3 is activating twice, don't activate it on release of space.

Comment: You've described a situation. It's not clear whether that's the situation you want (in which case, tell us what you already have), or it's what you have (in which case you should tell us what you want to change about it).

Comment: Okey sry :/ At the moment I have a simple static texture. Now I want to animate my sprite. The texture is a simple human. When the user press the enter button, the human gets into state2. This is the standart state during gameplay. If the user presses now "space" the sprite should get into state4(4th texture). This would be very unsmooth, so I decided to make a State3(ist just displayed very short to make the animation smooth). Now the sprite is in state4. If the user now releas the "space"-key the sprite should return into State2. For smoothness there is State3 short between.

Comment: So what's the actual problem? Do you not want it to enter State3 after releasing the space bar?

Comment: yeah my problem is, that State3 should just be displayed for a very short time.

Answer (score 1):

Add a timer for transition between states and then decrease the time during state3.
For examples:

```
enum State
     {
        state1,
        state2,
        state3,
        state4
     }


float timer;

// Your game loop update function
void Update()
{
   switch(state)
   {
      case State.state3:
           timer -= Time.detlaTime; // delta between frames in miliseconds
           if(timer <= 0)
           {
              state = State.state4;
           }
           break;
           /* Your 
           *  logic
           *  here
           */
```